# Expression changed after it has been checked between parent component and child in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a parent component that calls a child loading spinner component.

I'm using a property to pass a message.

In the parent component

```
<app-loading-spinner textBloc="LOADING_DATA_IN_PROGRESS"></app-loading-spinner>
```

In the child component

```
export class LoadingSpinnerComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() textBloc: string;

  constructor(
    public activeModal: NgbActiveModal,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() { }
}
```

In HTML of child component

```
<div class="text-center">
  <label>
    <p [innerHTML]='textBloc | translate'></p>
  </label>
</div>
```

I'm using translation module to render text from json file

```
"LOADING_DATA_IN_PROGRESS": "Chargement des données en cours, veuillez patienter...",
```

When I load the page I get this error

```
ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'innerHTML: undefined'. Current value: 'innerHTML: Chargement des données en cours, veuillez patienter...'. It seems like the view has been created after its parent and its children have been dirty checked. Has it been created in a change detection hook ?
```

I have read many article about this error but couldn't get when `textBloc` is undefined .

I tried to initalise `textBloc` inside the constructor

```
constructor(
  public activeModal: NgbActiveModal,
) { 
  this.textBloc='';
}
```

Comment: do you get the same error if you use `<p>{{textBloc | translate}}</p>` instead of binding to innerHTML?

Comment: Yes first it was like this

Comment: Did you try using the ngOnChanges hook on your child component?

`
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
     if (changes.textBloc) {
         this.textBloc = changes.textBloc.currentValue;
     }
   }
`

Comment: your child component doesn't modify the input `text` before the DOM is rendered, so I guess your directive is the culprit here. what does your `| translte`do ? Does it modify `textBloc` ?

Comment: I'm using the [ngx-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core) library it translates the variable name to a string. but even when I delete `translate` I get the same error.

Comment: @infodev the problem is that your pipe first return *undefined* then it returns the correct value. Why does it return *undefined* ? + notice you have a syntax error, it should be : `<p [innerHTML]="'textBloc' | translate"></p>`